# source file with comma saperated and then use the java transformation to split the rows

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I have a source flat file with comma separated,file has header with start date and end date , the next line has all the filed names and continued with the data 
example of source file:

```
"2015-05-09","2015-06-05"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
"CARRIER ","CONTRACT          ","ELGBL/GRP         ","                  ","TOTAL FEES","TOTAL FEES     ","PMPM ACA    ","PMPM ACA    ","RETAIL      ","RETAIL      ","MEDICAID    ","MEDICAID    ","STATE    ","STATE    ","MAIL SERVICE","MAIL SERVICE","RETAIL      ","RETAIL      ","POSTAGE -   ","POSTAGE -   ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","SYSTEM      ","OTHER       ","OTHER       ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","          
"        ","                  ","                  ","                  ","COUNT     ","AMOUNT         ","METAL       ","METAL       ","DIRECTS     ","DIRECTS     ","            ","            ","HEALTH      ","HEALTH      ","CLAIMS      ","CLAIMS      ","PHARMACY    ","PHARMACY    ","BULK        ","BULK        ","MCRCF       ","MCRCF       ","MCRCP       ","MCRCP       ","MPA         ","MPA         ","MRXC        ","MRXC        ","PPACA       ","PPACA       ","QPC         ","QPC         ","RXSEL       ","RXSEL       ","SPCR        ","SPCR        ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","          
"        ","                  ","                  ","                  ","          ","               ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","COUNT       ","AMOUNT      ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","            ","          
"1234    ","ABCD5678          ","ABCOEFITEST1      ","                  ","         1","           1.60","       1","           1.60","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       
"1234    ","ABCD5678          ","ABC200074002      ","                  ","         6","           3.20","       2","           3.20","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       4","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       
"1234    ","ABCD5678          ","ABC200178002      ","                  ","         2","           1.60","       1","           1.60","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       1","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       
"1234    ","ABCD5678          ","ABC200197001      ","                  ","         1","           1.60","       1","           1.60","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       
"1234    ","ABCD5678          ","ABC200204002      ","                  ","         2","           3.20","       2","           3.20","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       
"1234    ","ABCD5678          ","ABC200204003      ","                  ","         2","           3.20","       2","           3.20","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       
"1234    ","ABCD5678          ","ABC200232002      ","                  ","         4","           1.60","       1","           1.60","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       3","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       
"1234    ","ABCD5678          ","ABC200300001      ","                  ","         7","           1.60","       1","           1.60","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       6","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       
"1234    ","ABCD5678          ","ABC200345002      ","                  ","         1","           1.60","       1","           1.60","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       
"1234    ","ABCD5678          ","ABC200414001      ","                  ","         9","           3.20","       2","           3.20","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       7","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       
"1234    ","ABCD5678          ","ABC200491003      ","                  ","         1","           1.60","       1","           1.60","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","       0","           0.00","
```

so now I am reading it as one long string with 1000 precision and then I want to use Java transformation and split them with column names which are spread across multiple header, and associate them with the values underneath. One input row will land as many target rows.

first thing:Read file line by line into a long string port.

Add "CurrentlyProcessedFileName" port to the source to capture the filename.
Count the number of rows read

Split the row on commas-- how do I implement this ?? guessing expression or java transformation and the below whole process  in java or can I use SP , bu how do I split the row on commas??

```
   If Current RowNumber = 1 Then    
        vINVC_BGN_DT := field1
        vINVC_END_DT := field2

   If Current RowNumber > 1
      If field1 != $$CARRIER Then
    NAME1 := NAME1 || field1  #Initialize NAME variables to an empty string
    NAME2 := NAME2 || field2
    NAME3 := NAME3 || field3  #repeat for each comma seperated field
      If field1 = $$CARRIER Then
    VALUE1 := field1
    VALUE2 := field2
    VALUE3 := field3          #repeat for each comma seperated field
```

For each source row, the number of output rows should equal the count of distinct Amount_types, (excluding empty ones)

```
   For i in NAME4.NAMEx loop
       if NAMEi is not spaces or null then generate row
           target.INVC_TYPE = "CLAIM"
           target.FILE_RECEIPT_SK
           target.CARRIER := VALUE1
           target.CNTRCT := VALUE2
           target.PBM_GROUP := VALUE3
           target.INVC_BGN_DT := vINVC_BGN_DT  #From row1
           target.INVC_END_DT := vINVC_END_DT  #From row1
           target.INVC_AMOUNT_TYPE := NAMEi
           target.INVC_AMOUNT := VALUEi
   end i loop..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normalizer to  split one row into multiple rows. In your case, you have to seperately process the first row, next 3 header rows and the data rows. For that create a seq no in an expression using a variable.

You can get the begin and end date in the expression itself: Ex.

```
begin_date:= iif(seq=1, field1, begin_date)
```

For seperating the header rows and data rows, use a rouer with conditions like `seq>1 && seq<=4` and `seq>4`

Now you can use a normalizer to split the row into multiple rows. For the data rows create 5 columns for carrier, contract, pbm_group, count and amount and set the occurrence of count and amount to the total no. or count or amount columns.

You can use another normalizer for the header columns similarly. Finally join the two flows using joiner transformation.

You can also use a java transformation, in the on input row tab, you have write a similar logic. For splitting the row you can use the split method. Ex:

```
String[] fields=row.split(",");
```

Now the array `fields` would contain all the fields as array elements. You can assign appropriate elements to output ports and call the Informatica's `generateRow()` method to create a target record.

Comment: Thanks for you input smack, I want to use java transformation  so here is the code which i used to split the rows which are comma separated.String[] str=Col1.split(","); 

for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
{ 
Out_Col1 = str[i]; 
Out_Col1 = Col1; 
generateRow(); 
}  how do i add the array fileds can you please show .

Comment: Yes you going in the right direction. As the first three fields are common for all rows, you do not have to put it inside for loop. You can just use str[0], str[1] and str[2]. Run the for loop from 3 to end with step 2 to get the amounts.

Comment: Samik,my question is after I split the file with the commas , first thing i need to do is find the length of the string how do I write code for If Current RowNumber = 1 Then    
        vINVC_BGN_DT := field1
        vINVC_END_DT := field2
can you show me an example in java  please

Comment: And another question, whenI am reading my source file , I am reading it as a long string , then how do I identify the first field and assign its value when it's like a long string?? example is the source file which i attached in the first request.